# How to collapse row and columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    '0': [42, 42, 42, 4, 4, 4, 17, 17, 17],
    '1': [81, 81, 81, 31, 31, 31, 54, 54, 54],
    '2': [13, 13, 13, 7, 7, 7, 33, 33, 33]})
```

And my goal is DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'goal': [42, 81, 13, 4, 31, 7, 17, 54, 33]
})
```

I've tried df.unstack() but didn't succeed

Have any ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: Something like: `df.groupby("user_id").first().stack().reset_index(1, drop=1)`?

Comment: Yes! @user3483203 it works! Exactly what I needed. Tank you!

Comment: @user3483203, you should post it as a solution, so the OP can mark as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the duplicates, melt and keep only the relevant columns:

```
(df.drop_duplicates()
   .melt('user_id', value_name='goal', ignore_index=False)
   .drop(columns='variable')
   .sort_index()
  )

 
   user_id  goal
0        0    42
0        0    81
0        0    13
3        1     4
3        1    31
3        1     7
6        2    17
6        2    54
6        2    33
```

Comment: My original DataFrame has 45000 rows and after df.drop_duplicates it shortens to 25000 but I need to keep all values.

Comment: in the example you posted, you are not keeping the values. maybe explain a bit more in your question, or give a better example that captures what you are after

Comment: Yep that's my bad, I've should been present more comprehensive example.

Answer (score 1):

Drop duplicates + [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on `user_id` + [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) , as follows:

```
(df.drop_duplicates()
   .set_index('user_id')
   .stack()
   .droplevel(-1)
   .reset_index(name='goal')
)
```

**Result:**

```
   user_id  goal
0        0    42
1        0    81
2        0    13
3        1     4
4        1    31
5        1     7
6        2    17
7        2    54
8        2    33
```

Comment: My original DataFrame has 45000 rows and after df.drop_duplicates it shortens to 25000 but I need to keep all values.

Comment: @VldmrSmrkv  Based on your sample data, different rows of the same `user_id` just have the same set of values in columns `0`, `1`, `2`.   So, dropping the duplicates and by transposing the data from repeating rows into different rows in a single column, we are not losing information.  The total rows in the result is the same as the original, isn't it ?